# Accept all subdomains except one in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have an application with many urls like this:

```
dashboard.app.mycooldomain.com 
subdomain-1.app.mycooldomain.com
subdomain-1.app.mycooldomain.com
subdomain-3.app.mycooldomain.com
subdomain-n.app.mycooldomain.com
```

and nginx config

```
  server {
    listen 5001 default;
    listen [::]:5001;

    server_name *.$hostname;

    location / {
      alias /usr/share/nginx/html/home/;
      index index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 5001;
    listen [::]:5001;

    server_name dashboard.*$hostname;

    location / {
      alias /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboard/;
      index index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;
    }
  }
```

I expect when I visit `dashboard.app.mycooldomain.com` or `dashboard.app.localhost` nginx should serve all static file in `/usr/share/nginx/html/home/` and when I `subdomain-1.app.mycooldomain.com` or `subdomain-1.app.localhost` or `*.app.mycooldomain.com` nginx should serve all static file in `/usr/share/nginx/html/dashboard/`. But now it does not work. How to write a config file correctly?

Comment: What does `*hostname` and `$hostname` mean?

Comment: I made a typo. `server_name dashboard.*$hostname;`

Comment: Ok, I've never used `$hostname` in a `server_name` directive. But the wildcard form only accepts an `*` as the first or last character. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Create subdomains files in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled for all the required/different hosts/url, this way it would be much easier to manage the domains.